# PHP MS SQL ID format problem

Tags: php, sql-server, string, formatting

I'm drawing records into PHP from a legacy MSSQL database built for/by an ASP.net application.

The id's in ASP appear as long strings of numbers but when retrieved by PHP are in a form like so:

```
3;Í}±¯I©ûzƒgŸó
```

Comment: You will need to show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to wager that the IDs are actually GUIDs -- if so you will want to convert your GUIDs to strings using [mssql-guid-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-guid-string.php) (or if you are using PHP 5.3 or later you will want to use Microsoft's [SqlSrv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) extension, which should convert GUID fields automatically.)

Comment: Removed in PHP 7.0

Comment: From the comments in the manual, the removed function can be replaced with `function convertBinToMSSQLGuid($binguid)
{
        $unpacked = unpack('Va/v2b/n2c/Nd', $binguid);
        return sprintf('%08X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%08X', $unpacked['a'], $unpacked['b1'], $unpacked['b2'], $unpacked['c1'], $unpacked['c2'], $unpacked['d']);
}`

Comment: @SeanVieira you saved our lives, awesome function I wish I could up-vote you more

Answer (score 4):

In PHP 7 and up you now have to "tell" PDO to use the string representation of the GUID when returning it as opposed to the default binary representation.

See: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2001

**Solution:**

```
     /* $db represent the PDO connection */
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, true);
```

Comment: this option seems no longer available on the PDO class? has it been replaced with a newer optoin?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function. It retuns cenverted mssql id. 
Example: G4G3G2G1-G6G5-G8G7-G9G10-G11G12G13G14G15G16

```
 function convertBinToMSSQLGuid($binguid)
 {
    $unpacked = unpack('Va/v2b/n2c/Nd', $binguid);
    return sprintf('%08X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%08X', $unpacked['a'], $unpacked['b1'], $unpacked['b2'], $unpacked['c1'], $unpacked['c2'], $unpacked['d']);
 }
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

set in connection following attribute 
PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
as true

source https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2001